# convergence of a nonnegative monotonic sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ be a non-negative sequence of real numbers. Assume that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_k-a_{k-1}\leq 0$, that is, the sequence is monotonically decreasing. Moreover assume that $\lim_{k\to\infty} (a_k-a_{k-1})=0$. Can we prove or disprove by counter-example that $a_k$ converges? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to invoke the Monotone convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) because the sequence is bounded from below (by 0) and decreasing. We did not even use the assumption $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k-a_{k-1}=0$; in fact, knowing that $a_k$ converges, you can prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(a_k-a_{k-1})= \lim_{k\to\infty}a_k-\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{k-1}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions for [monotone convergence theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) are satisfied, hence it converges.

That is it is decreasing and bounded below.

Answer (score 1):

So $a_{n}\geq 0$, $n=1,2,...$, so the sequence is bounded below, and $\inf_{n}a_{n}$ exists, one can show that $a_{n}\rightarrow\inf_{n}a_{n}$ since $\{a_{n}\}$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

No counterexample as others have already pointed out: the sequence is convergent since it is decreasing and nonnegative.

You would have a counterexample if you change "decreasing" to "increasing" in your question: think about the harmonic series.